# Signup and Login via SMS OTP using AWS cognito

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am trying to integrate SMS OTP based signup and login flow using AWS Cognito with an expressJS backend.

What I need is just following basic functionalities:

1. After `/sendSMS` API is called in express app, OTP should be sent to that phone number.
2. On `/verifySMS` API, verification of phone number and OTP should happen and user should be created in userpool.
3. On `/resendSMS` API, resend the OTP to that specific phone number.

I am able to send OTP to phone number using `userPool.signUp` method of npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js). But this only allows signing up and not login. Also, this is not possible without password.

How to implement above functionalities without password and also for login?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement a [custom authentication flow](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/switch-auth/q/platform/js#custom_auth-flow). Here are some articles that explain exactly how to create such a flow using OTP over SMS:

- https://techinscribed.com/passwordless-phone-number-authentication-using-aws-amplify-cognito/
- https://hnp.dev/otp-based-phone-auth-amazon-cognito-amplify/
- https://itnext.io/passwordless-sms-authentication-backend-9932391c49dc

Comment: Thanks @Russell. Let me go through them.

Comment: just be aware that when you use custom authentication you lose a lot. You can't use the "custom UI" which means you not only lose the scopes (and consequently OIDC) but you lose the flows like code flow which can complicate mobile apps, etc.

Comment: MFA auth using OTP is already supported in Cognito. However, what I am struggling with is how to resend the SMS OTP if let's say the user didn't get the SMS in the first attempt

Comment: @MandeepSingh how do you activate MFA auth with OTP via API? I've tried it but I couldn't put the endpoints together. I don't know what's the exact flow